# Unable to grant datastore permissions in Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-iam

When managing roles in Google Cloud IAM, all datastore.* permissions (such as datastore.entities.{create, list, get}) show up as greyed out with a yellow exclamation badge with a tool tip explaining "cannot assign permission."

I'm assuming this is why all datastore api calls result in "com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Missing or insufficient permissions" even when assigning project level rights to the role.

Any idea how to grant these permissions to roles?

Comment: Are you the Owner of the project?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bear in mind that “Custom roles are a beta feature and should be used with caution.”

It is a known issue in [Beta restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles?hl=en_US&_ga=2.92002076.-743583840.1513068737&_gac=1.137039364.1513170593.EAIaIQobChMI37jalvSG2AIVF40bCh2u-wmtEAAYASAAEgJk5_D_BwE#beta_restrictions):

> “Some predefined roles contain deprecated permissions or permissions that are otherwise not permitted in custom roles. A custom role that is based on a predefined role that contains deprecated or restricted permissions will not contain those permissions.”

Also if you check the IAM Permissions Change Log, in [Upcoming IAM changes for the week of 2017-12-18](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-change-log) , you will see all these roles related to Cloud Datastore are not longer supported in Customer Roles.

In this case you will have to use [Primitive roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#primitive_roles).